# Pytest-xdist works with pip but not with pipenv. No tests are loaded/scheduled

Tags: python, pytest, pipenv, xdist

`Pytest` works when I have it installed through pip and pipenv. However, when using the `pytest-xdist` plugin with the command e.g `pytest -n 4`, this only works with `pip` and not `pipenv`. No tests are scheduled or loaded.

```
mohammad@mohammad-XPS-15-9550:~/Documents/cs203/gatorgrouper$ pipenv run pytest tests/ -n 4
Test session starts (platform: linux, Python 3.6.7, pytest 4.2.1, pytest-sugar 0.9.2)
cachedir: .pytest_cache
hypothesis profile 'default' -> database=DirectoryBasedExampleDatabase('/home/mohammad/Documents/cs203/gatorgrouper/.hypothesis/examples')
rootdir: /home/mohammad/Documents/cs203/gatorgrouper, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: xdist-1.26.1, sugar-0.9.2, forked-1.0.2, cov-2.6.1, clarity-0.1.0a1, hypothesis-4.5.11
[gw0] linux Python 3.6.7 cwd: /home/mohammad/Documents/cs203/gatorgrouper
[gw1] linux Python 3.6.7 cwd: /home/mohammad/Documents/cs203/gatorgrouper
[gw2] linux Python 3.6.7 cwd: /home/mohammad/Documents/cs203/gatorgrouper
[gw3] linux Python 3.6.7 cwd: /home/mohammad/Documents/cs203/gatorgrouper
[gw0] Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)  -- [GCC 8.2.0]
[gw1] Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)  -- [GCC 8.2.0]
[gw2] Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)  -- [GCC 8.2.0]
[gw3] Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)  -- [GCC 8.2.0]
gw0 [0] / gw1 [0] / gw2 [0] / gw3 [0]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling


Results (1.05s):
```

Here is my current pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"
black = "*"
pytest = "*"
six = "*"
codecov = "*"
"flake8" = "*"
pytest-cov = "*"
neovim = "*"
pytest-sugar = "*"
pytest-clarity = "*"
autopep8 = "*"
gspread =  "*"
oauth2client = "*"
pytest-xdist = "*"

[packages]
pathlib = "*"
py = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well.
Seems that pytest-xdist does not support pytest-clarity.
Just remove it. Launching the tests in parallel again should work now for you.

```
pip uninstall pytest-clarity
```

Regards!